# Basic SQLlite sql update fails with criptic error

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I'm currently building a phonegap app.

One page contains a form that allows the signed in user to update basic settings. On this page I have a "update" button that calls a JS function which updates the DB with the changed settings. However, I seem to be unable to get even the most basic update working.

Heres a (much simplified) example.

```
function updateSettings(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('UPDATE USERS SET (username) VALUES ("edit") WHERE id = 1');
}

db.transaction(updateSettings, errorCB);
```

Running this (and pretty much every other update ive tried) gives me this error:

```
Error processing SQL: could not prepare statement (1 near "(": syntax error)
```

The slightly more complicated query I was originally trying to run was this:

```
tx.executeSql('UPDATE USERS SET (username, password, userId, defaultHandler, autoSync, updateCT, updateHistorical, updateFavorite, signedIn) VALUES ("'+ username +'", "'+ password +'", "plUserId", "Default Handle", "'+ sync +'", "' + updateCaseTypes + '", "' + updateHistoricalCases + '", "' + updateFavoriteCases +'", "1") WHERE id = 1');
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not valid SQL. See the [SQLite documentation on `UPDATE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html).

```
UPDATE USERS set username = 'edit' where id = 1;
```